# One-liner to conditionally swap a value

Tags: python

I've got a variable that can hold one of two values. This simple logic reverses it:

```
opt_in_status = some_method_that_returns_an_opt_in_status()
# switch the opt_in_status
opt_in_status = "opted_in" if opt_in_status == "unsubscribed" else "unsubscribed"
```

I don't like the fact that I've hardcoded the magic string `unsubscribed` twice. I could put that into another variable

```
opt_in_status = some_method_that_returns_an_opt_in_status()
# switch the opt_in_status
magic_string = "unsubscribed"
opt_in_status = "opted_in" if opt_in_status == magic_string else magic_string
```

but is there a more concise one-liner that will do this for me?

I'm using python 3.9

Comment: `... (magic_string := "unsubscribed") else magic_string`? what version of python?

Comment: If you're using Python 3.8+ you can do it with https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/, but I don't think it would improve readability.

Comment: Surely you can/should incorporate that logic into `some_method_that_returns_an_opt_in_status`? Perhaps by using some arguments with default values

Comment: @DeepSpace yes I can, this is just a contrived example

Comment: just those 2 possibilities? why then not `has_opted_in = True/False`? you could then use `not` for example...

Comment: `opt_in_status = set([opt_in_status , "opted_in", "unsubscribed"]).difference({opt_in_status }).pop()` might do it, but maybe not easy to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python 3.8 you can use the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/) `:=`

```
opt_in_status = "opted_in" if opt_in_status == (magic_string := "unsubscribed") else magic_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably outside the scope of the question, but I think this use-case really asks for using enum values.

```
from enum import Enum

class OptInStatus(Enum):
    UNSUBSCRIBED = False
    OPTED_IN = True

optInStatus = OptInStatus(False)
print(optInStatus.name)    #UNSUBSCRIBED

optInStatus = OptInStatus(not optInStatus.value)    # Here is where the swap happens
print(optInStatus.name)    #OPTED_IN
```

This way reverse operation is much shorter, clearer in its effects and there are no magic strings involved at all. Of course, this would require interface change or conversion from string return values like so:

```
    @classmethod
    def fromString(cls, string):
        if string == "unsubscribed":
            return cls.UNSUBSCRIBED
        elif string == "opted_in":
            return cls.OPTED_IN

optInStatus = OptInStatus.fromString("unsubscribed")
```